# Disable alt key temporary c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm searching a way to disable alt and ctrl key input while I'm pressing it.
I'm actually developping a Macro Configurer and when I press my macro (for example Alt+Ctrl+NumPad0) and I want that the keys H+E+L+L+O are sent, it won't work because I'm pressing Alt. The computer probably tries to execute unknown shortcuts for Alt+Ctrl+H, Alt+Ctrl+E ... 
So I want that when I press my macro and the program detects I pressed it, it disable temporary alt while the output keys are sent, and enable again Alt when it's finished.
I use a LowLevelKeyboardProc to detect when i press a key, but I can't prevent the Alt pressing because i'm actually pressing it to execute my macro.

//The code from my form

```
private void Listener_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyUpArgs e)
{
    KeyAction.RemoveKeyDown(e.KeyUp);
}


private void Listener_OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        KeyAction.PutKeyDown(e.KeyPressed);
        foreach (MacroEntree macro in macros)
        {
            if (macro.Activated)
                if (macro.Action != null)
                    if (macro.isMacroDown())
                    {
                        listener.OnKeyPressed -= new EventHandler<KeyPressedArgs>(Listener_OnKeyPressed);
                        new Thread(delegate ()
                        {
                            while (IsAltCtrlDown()) ;
                            macro.ExecuteAction();
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            listener.OnKeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyPressedArgs>(Listener_OnKeyPressed);

                        }).Start();
                    }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Erreur : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
private bool IsAltCtrlDown()
{
    if (KeyAction.isKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || KeyAction.isKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
        return true;
    if (KeyAction.isKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || KeyAction.isKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        return true;
    return false;
}


//the code from my class that checks if the macro is down
public class KeyAction
{
   static List<Key> keyDown = new List<Key>();

    public static bool isKeyDown(Key k)
    {
        return keyDown.Contains(k);
    }
    public static void PutKeyDown(Key k)
    {
        if (!keyDown.Contains(k))
            keyDown.Add(k);
    }
    public static void RemoveKeyDown(Key k)
    {
        keyDown.Remove(k);
    }
```

}

Comment: Can't you sent a `KeyUp` for Ctrl + Alt? Maybe that way the system might think you already released the keys (with keybd_event).

Comment: I will try this,I didn't think about it.

Comment: Edit : I just tried it and it's working, it was too easy to think about it.... Thank you !!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could post the actual solution as an answer to this question so people with the same problem can use it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Manfred Radlwimmer I solved the problem. I send a Alt and Ctrl key up before executing my action and it works fine.

```
    private void Listener_OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyAction.PutKeyDown(e.KeyPressed);
            foreach (MacroEntree macro in macros)
            {
                if (macro.Activated)
                    if (macro.Action != null)
                        if (macro.isMacroDown())
                        {
                            listener.OnKeyPressed -= new EventHandler<KeyPressedArgs>(Listener_OnKeyPressed);
                            new Thread(delegate ()
                            {
                                KeyboardOperations.SendKeyUp(KeyboardOperations.KeyCode.LALT);
                                KeyboardOperations.SendKeyUp(KeyboardOperations.KeyCode.LCONTROL);

                                macro.ExecuteAction();
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                                listener.OnKeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyPressedArgs>(Listener_OnKeyPressed);

                            }).Start();
                        }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Erreur : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set a [`low-level keyboard hook`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/) to swallow keyboard input messages in windows.

Every native Windows program bases on a so called [`message loop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223270/6583901) that is basicly this.

```
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{ 
    TranslateMessage(&msg); 
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}
```

With an `low-level keyboard hook` you can handle messages in this loop on the `desktop` process and with that prevent keys from being pressed.

```
public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(
    int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
{
    return SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL, 
        proc, 
        0, // hook on all input (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715480/is-zero-ever-a-valid-handle)
        0); // for all threads
}
```

You can use the code like the following. When you do not call `CallNextHookEx` the key event will not have any impact.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

private static IntPtr HookCallback(
    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    // check if it is a key down message
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        // check if the pressed key is the `Alt` key
        if((Keys)vkCode == Keys.Alt)
        {
            // return 1 for handled if its the alt key
            return (IntPtr) 1; 
        }
    } 

    // let the message bubble if its not a keydown message or it wasn't the alt key which was pressed               
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

// with this line you can set the `HookCallback` into the message loop
IntPtr hookID = SetHook(HookCallback);
```

And don't forget to unset the hook.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID);
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. I've already tried this but I can't prevent the Alt key to be pressed if I'm actually pressing it to execute my macro. I would need to disable Alt key while I'm pressing it and until the executed action is finished.

Comment: @FosheusBadabu How is the code supposed to determine if any key is being pressed as a part of the macro or not? What if the user presses the Alt key, but waits a minute and a half to complete the macro?

Comment: Sorry for late response.The macro will be executed a minute and a half later, and tht's not what i want. I've an event in the Hookcallback that my form catches. I've also a class that check if the macro is down. When a key is catch in the event, I check if other keys are down with my class (It's a list that I fill and clean when ever a key is being down or up), and while the macro is down I wait until alt and ctrl are released.

Comment: @FosheusBadabu this is a problem related to your other code. show code samples about what you have done. But think about it first if its related to this question or a compleatly new one

Comment: I actually know how to disable certain key but i just want to disable the alt key for some µseconds to execute my macro and reenable it after. The problem is that i can't disable alt key in the HookCallback because I'm already pressing it.